# Make two plots in a single row using imshow in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I want to make plots of the same data for two regions, so they should be placed side by side in a single row for compactness.

Below is my code. As we can expect, it's creating the plots one after another in a column, since the two plots are not linked to each other.

I tried looking for side by side plot methods, however they don't seem to work with `imshow()` and I need to use `imshow()` in my code. I've attached my output below as well.

Any suggestions?

```
wvcount3D=fanibl['IMG_WV'][:]
wvcount3D.shape
wvcount=np.squeeze(wvcount3D)
wvcount.shape
image_wv_global=plt.imshow(wvcount,vmin=800,vmax=975)
plt.title("Global 2D plot for Water Vapor Count for Fani before landfall")
plt.colorbar(image_wv_global)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

image_wv_asia=plt.imshow(wvcount,vmin=800,vmax=975)
plt.title("Asia-specific plot for Water Vapor Count for Fani before landfall")
plt.axis([300, 1000, 200, 700])
plt.colorbar(image_wv_asia)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This is my current output, plots in a single column:

[image: This is my current output, plots in a single column]

Comment: with  [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: directly using 'plt' for relatively complex layout is not recommended from my personal experiences, see [Artist tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html), this is very nice primer intro.

Comment: @ted930511 I'm approaching the problem differently for now. By whatever means, I need to use `imshow()`. Let me explain it briefly. So, I've a 2D numpy.ndarray called wvcount. I need to create two plots from it (one global and one Asia-specific). I'm calling the `image_wv_global=plt.imshow(wvcount)` for that which gives me a nice plot. By restricting axes appropriately, I get Asia specific plot image_wv_asia easily . These two plots are matplotlib.image.AxesImage dtype. I just need to arrange them in a row but I can't find a way. Any suggestions would be helpful.